# Shopping Cart doesn't update quantity

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, upgrade, ce-1.9.2.2

When I try to update the cart qty of any product it doesn't change anything, is always set to

The **`cart.phtml`** has already set the **`form_key`**: `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>`... so, i don't know what is happening here. Everything seems to be in order.

Any clues?

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you are using one of the es_ locales.

I reported this bug for M1 here: https://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/1200 (you'll need to be logged in).

Also, I reported the problem from M2: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3619

To be fair this isn't a problem of Magento by itself. There's an error when Zend_Locale try to validate the number but this isn't a problem of Zend_Locale neither.

I was trying to find a fix but I wasn't able to fix it yet. I hope that after the bug reports Magento or Zend can help to find a solution.

Comment: Exactly! i'm using es_CL in fact... our platform has the same issue that you reported in magentocommerce... If i find anything to fix it i will report here the solution. fingerS cross :p

Answer (score 1):

place the below code to your

/app/design/frontend/yourthemepackage/yourtheme/template/checkout/cart.phtml file:

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

into the line 50 just after:

```
getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost') ?>" method="post">
```

This way you will fix the update of the products quantity in the shopping cart.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue **AFTER** I had added an SSL certificate and I found that if I changed the unsecure base to:

Base URL: https://example.com.au (add your own site here)
Base Link URL: {{secure_base_url}}

I also changed the skin, media & javascript url to {{secure_base_url}}/skin (etc)

On a side note, I found that this change also fixed an issue where **REQUIRED** custom option on a product initially would not get accepted. After doing the above change I had not more issue with it :)